# Xamarin C# cross-platform timeout timer

Tags: c#, xamarin, timer, portable-class-library

I need a very standard thing, a timeout timer, but it's for a PCL (Portable Class Library) Xamarin app, and there's a lot of functionality missing there.   The interface I need looks something like this:

```
class Timeout
{
    // The 'OnTimeout' event is triggered when at least numSeconds have elapsed
    public delegate void VoidFunc();
    public event VoidFunc OnTimeout;

    // Construct the Timeout object and start the timer.
    public Timeout(int numSeconds);

    // Restart the timer.
    public void Restart();
}
```

So if I construct the Timeout object at 12:00:00 as Timeout(30), then call Restart() at 12:00:29, the event fires exactly once, at 12:00:59.

Unfortunately, Xamarin cross-platform doesn't have a Timer class, so I can imagine two possibilities:

1) Construct a timer using Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer when the Timeout object is constructed, and have it keep firing every second (or every quarter second or something).  Every time it fires, it checks if it's supposed to trigger the event or not.

2) Start up a thread in the Timeout() constructor, have it sleep most of the time but wake up every second (or quarter second) and check if it's time to fire the event.

Neither of these options seems great to me -

1) Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer works with the UI thread, so it's potentially less accurate (if the UI is busy, the event won't fire).

2) System overhead of constructing a thread, and coding overhead of making sure the thread shuts down pleasantly if the Timeout() object is destructed before the event is fired.

Both options end up wasting a tiny bit of CPU every time they wake up and realize it's not time to fire the event, certainly not a huge deal but the kind of thing I usually try to avoid doing.

Is there a more elegant solution that I'm missing?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mobilist.AdvancedTimer.Forms.Plugin/

Comment: You can always create a dependencyservice and implement the timers natively.